# Informations in asset disapear after a put

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I work in hyperledger composer. On model cto I define 
- an asset Child which contains a list of vaccine. This asset is defined by :

```
asset Child identified by childId {
      o String childId
      o String name
      o String surname
      o DateTime dateOfBirth
      o Vaccin[] vaccins optional
      --> Parent hasparent
      --> Doctor hasdoctor
    }
```

- an asset defVaccin which contains some definitions of vaccines. A vaccin is defined by :

`asset defVaccin identified by vaccinId {
      o String vaccinId
      o String diseases
      o Integer timeFirst
      o Integer timeSecond optional
      o Integer timeThird optional
      o Integer timeFourth optional
      o Integer timeFifth optional
    }`

To create/add vaccines in this list, I use a transaction "vaccinate" which is defined like this on the model cto :

```
transaction Vaccinate {
  --> Child inchild 
  --> defVaccin aboutvaccin
  o DateTime dateOfVaccin
}
```

And like this on logic.js

```
function vaccinate(vaccinate) {

var factory = getFactory();
var vaccin = factory.newConcept('vaccinspace', 'Vaccin', vaccinate.aboutvaccin.vaccinId); // create vaccin concept

// define value of concept's properties
vaccin.vaccinId = vaccinate.aboutvaccin.vaccinId;
vaccin.dateOfVaccin = vaccinate.dateOfVaccin;

// add this vaccine at the list of child's vaccines
vaccinate.inchild.addArrayValue("vaccins", vaccin)

return getAssetRegistry('vaccinspace.Child')
.then (function (assetRegistry) {
return assetRegistry.update(vaccinate.inchild); // update the list of child's vaccines
});
}
```

This works fine, i have all my vaccines in my list. But if i modifie my child or my vaccin (just do a put to change child's name for exemple), i have an empty list after.

Does someone knows why my informations "disapear" from my list ? How can i change this?

Comment: can you supply the definition of the other elements of the model - Child etc.

Comment: I added this on my question

Answer (score 0):

see example here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/carauction-network/lib/logic.js#L89

try

```
// add this vaccine to the list of child's vaccines array of concepts
vaccinate.inchild.vaccins.push(vaccin);
```

instead of

```
 // add this vaccine at the list of child's vaccines
vaccinate.inchild.addArrayValue("vaccins", vaccin);
```